# Close GtkNativeDialog

Tags: c++, gtk3

I followed the GTK3 example on how to prompt a openFileDialog from a console based application.
For some strange reason, when I select a file, the dialog stays open (it kind of "hangs").
My program, in the meantime, goes on, with the correct filename.

I am just stuck on this piece.

```
string requestInputFile()
{
    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);
    GtkFileChooserNative *native;
    gint res;
    string filename = "";

    native = gtk_file_chooser_native_new((gchar *)"Open File", NULL, GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, "Open", "Cancel");

    auto filter = gtk_file_filter_new();
    gtk_file_filter_set_name(filter, "Excel");
    gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*.xlsx");

    gtk_file_chooser_add_filter(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(native), filter);

    GtkNativeDialog *filedialog = GTK_NATIVE_DIALOG (native);
    res = gtk_native_dialog_run (filedialog);

    if (res == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
    {
        GtkFileChooser *chooser = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (native);
        filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (chooser);
    }

    g_object_unref(native);

    return filename;
}
```

Comment: Change `g_object_unref` to `gtk_widget_destroy`, it should solve the issue.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev, that doens't work. Since 'native' isn't a GtkWidget: `cannot convert ‘GtkFileChooserNative* {aka _GtkFileChooserNative*}’ to ‘GtkWidget* {aka _GtkWidget*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void gtk_widget_destroy(GtkWidget*)’
  gtk_widget_destroy(native)